# Hibernate Mapping many-to-many

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to map a non standard relationship. I have to tables:

### Parent_Table

id_table
cod_atribute

### Child_Table

id_child_table1
id_child_table2
atributes

What I pretend is to join these two tables by cod_atribute = id_child_table1 association through hbm mapping file.

In my Parent_Table class entity I have a Set of Child_Table objects. If I define a one-to-many association the generated join statement is by id_table=id_child_table1. If I define many-to-many association I have an error because it is necessary to define id_child_table1 and id_child_table2 as foreign key.

Could you help me to successfully build this relationship?

Thanks.
JB

Answer (score 0):

you need the property ref in the set to tell hibernate to join on that *property* instead

```
<set name="childs" property-ref="cod">
```